# How to Tell R What Day of the week should be the start or end day of the week?

Tags: r, time-series, xts, dayofweek, weekend

When converting a daily XTS object in R to weekly using to.weekly() function, The weekly XTS object has week-endings on "Sunday". How is it possible to set the week-endings to be on "Saturday" instead?

Comment: I'm no expert at `xts`, but I'm struggling to make this happen. `to.weekly()` is essentially `to.period(x,"weeks")`, which relies on `endpoints()`, which doesn't seem to have an option to change when weeks end/start, though I could be missing something simple.